# Check if sender is @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this method:

```
void myMethod(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {...}
```

And I call it sometimes by @Html.ActionLink and sometimes by clicking on a cell in table which has the class 'clickableCell'.
How to check what was the sender, if it is a link?

It's type in both cases is WebClient.

Comment: Can't you add this info to the `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs`?

Comment: @DavidePiras Do you mean as another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a user state object when calling it:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += myMethod;

// You could pass any object
string state = "foo bar";

client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://foo.bar.com"), state);
```

and then:

```
void myMethod(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // will equal "foo bar"
    string state = e.UserState as string;
    ...
}
```

Comment: But I can't do this. In both cases I have the same method. Once I call it by Response.Redirect(Url.Action("act", "contr")); and once by <li id="someId">@Html.ActionLink("act", "act", "contr")</li>

Comment: @Srcee, in this case you will have to pass an additional query string parameter to this action so that it can distinguish between the 2 cases. For example: `Url.Action("act", "contr", new { value = "case1" })` or whatever.